# Angular JS http GET request with basic authentication

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular JS. Here is the snippet of the code I have.

I am trying a GET request against a URL with basic authentication. This works fine with CURL or even in the browser. So, there is no problem with the URL that is being accessed.

I tried the following 2 ways to connect using the basic authentication. This does not return anything in the response. Any idea what is missing here?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['base64']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   var auth = $base64.encode("Username:Password");
   var headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth};
   var url="<URL>";
   $http.get(url,{headers: headers}).then(function(response) {
             $scope.myData = resonpse.somthing;
          });
});
```

And:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['base64']);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

     $http({
         method : "GET",
         url : "<URL>"
         headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic <encoded string>',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                                         }
         }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
                 $scope.myData = response.something;
     });
});
```

Comment: Well, resonpse.somthing will throw an exception, since resonpse is undefined.

Comment: are you receiving any errors from your backend? try extending the callback: `$http.get(url, headers).then((res) => {...}, (err) => {...})`

Comment: can you write the error callback too? Maybe something is going wrong with the API. What do you see in networks of developers console?

Comment: The error callback is not returning anything. I tried status and statusText.  The same code works if I try it against a URL which is open and does not require any username & password, so I believe response variable is correct here. Anything else I am missing?

Comment: @MePunekar have you acknowledged a typo `resonpse` != `response`?